# What's the difference between op-amp and power amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, power-amplifier

Can u give me the detail answer with some point about the difference

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately for you, this is not a free design consultancy, where you ask a short question and get the hard work of lengthy custom-written answers in return. People here will be happy to help you if they see that you've written a detailed question and gone as far as can be expected on your own. Again, welcome.

Comment: More importantly, this is too broad for the format of this site. There are detailed articles on Wikipedia covering the topic, why don't you read these first?

Comment: @AntonIo just check the datasheets and the current output.

Answer (score 7):

**Opamp** *(Operational amplifier)* is a special device that gives you the ability of performing some "operations" *(summing, subtracting, integration, differentiation, sign changing, filtering, converting, comparing etc.)* as well as amplification on at least one signal. Maybe the most distinctive feature is having extremely high input impedance and low output impedance which is quite useful for buffering.

Opamps are generally low-power *(I say "generally low-power" because there are even ultra-low-power devices on the market)* devices and have limited output power (e.g. a few tens of mW).

A good example to usage of an opamp can be driving a headphone: Suppose you have a signal coming from a dynamic microphone *(output impedance can be a few hundreds, say, 250 Ohms)* having 2mV of amplitude (= 1.41mVrms) and you want to hear the sound from a 32-ohm headphone. The required power level is a few tens of mW (say, 20mW = about 1mA ouput current x 20mV output voltage) and since the output impedance of microphone is quite high compared to the load *(remember a voltage divider: Vo = Vi x 32/(32+250) = 0.1Vi)* and output current is limited (a few microamps), you cannot drive the headphone directly from microphone. An opamp can be used for this application because it can amplify both voltage (about x20) and current (about x10 to x100) to the required level.

**Voltage Amplifiers**, as the name suggests, amplify the input **voltage** to a certain level. They are not expected to have high output power, because their main job is to amplify only the "voltage", so they can have high output impedance (e.g. a few kOhms). Note that a voltage amplifier can be built from an opamp.

**Power Amplifiers**, as the name suggests, amplify both voltage and current to higher levels to drive high-power loads where other amplifiers are not sufficient to do the job.

The best example is an audio power amplifier: Suppose you have a microphone signal having 2mV of amplitude (= 1.41mVrms) and you want to hear the sound from an 8ohm-10W speaker. From P = V²/R = I²R, you'll need 3.5Vrms = 5Vp of output voltage and 1.1Arms = 1.6Ap of output current. None of the opamps can provide such a high current. So you'll need a power amplifier. A voltage amplifier or an opamp can be used before power amplifier for both amplifying and filtering.

Power amplifiers can be named from their class (e.g. Class A, Class AB, Class D etc) and each class have advantages and disadvantages according to the application.

An interesting detail here is a Class AB push pull power amplifier has nothing different from an opamp except maximum power delivery.

hth.